# What this the first three characters inside xml

Tags: java, arrays, controls, byte, special-characters

Why i got following output by reading the content of file as byte array with java?

```
File f = new File( "exampleData.xml" );
byte[] data = getBytesFromFile("data.xml");
for (byte zeichen : data) {
    char zzeichenCharacter = (char)zeichen;
    System.out.println(zzeichenCharacter + "  : " + String.valueOf(zeichen));
}
```

Output:

```
￯  : -17
ﾻ  : -69
﾿  : -65
<  : 60
?  : 63
```

And when I copy the content from the file exampleData.xml to a second file with name exampleDataCopy.xml and using the same code above I got a different output:

```
<  : 60
?  : 63
x  : 120
m  : 109
l  : 108
```

Comment: What encoding do the files have?

Comment: BTW, `String.valueOf(0xff & zeichen)` would give the unsigned byte, which is probably a more "natural" way to print a byte.

Answer (score 1):

The first three bytes are the UTF-8 encoding of the [Byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

The hexadecimal representation is `EF BB BF`.

You should read your file as UTF-8 instead of processing it byte by byte.